# How to fit a probability distribution function (pdf) in R given the zscore, mean and standard deviation of a dataset

Tags: r, gaussian

I am trying to fit a normal pdf provided zscore, mean and standard deviation.I am using dnorm(zscore,mean,sd) to fit a normal pdf. But, I am not sure if dnorm  can be used to fit a normal pdf with the zscore value.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Normal densities have two parameters. The zscore parameter is superfluous, though of course once you have a density you can evaluate it anywhere you want, including at a number you are thinking of as a zscore. I'm not sure of the motivation behind that evaluation, though.

Comment: I think we can fit a normal pdf using 'dnorm' for any normal dataset, but my question is :How do we get a pdf if only  zscore, mean and sd is known?

Comment: `dnorm(x,mean,sd)` *is* the pdf. I don't see the relevance of any zscore. You say you already know the only 2 parameters you need to know when specifying a normal distribution. There are important questions about how good the fit is, but even there I don't see any direct relevance of any zscore, especially when you haven't explained what this zscore is supposed to represent and how you have calculated it from the data.